# I need to run service multiple times android

Tags: android, service

I'm wraiting task_manager app. This app working as follow: user choose "if event is happening" and choose "then turn something". In this app I'm using NotificationManager and AlarmReceiver for if f.e. if is 22:00 run Service which push notification on task bar.

I have a problem because I can have only 1 instance of servie. So if user create and turn on every day on 8:00 send me notification "Good morning" and create task every day on 12:00 "It's luch time". Only first task working.

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do a task one time then automatically kill the service then use IntentService for it , you can read it here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html